# GTK+ Thread safety

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, gtk

I'm trying to use threads to manage several things in GTK+, however, as soon as I try to use any GUI function in the new thread, it locks up the GUI and this makes sense since GTK+ is not thread safe. Is there anyway around this?

Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   

 GError *error = NULL;

/* init threads */  
g_thread_init(NULL);
gdk_threads_init();

/* init gtk */
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

....

//Multithreaded functions
g_thread_create(argument_thread, (gpointer)label7, FALSE, &error );

gdk_threads_enter();
gtk_main();
gdk_threads_leave();
return 0;
}

void *argument_thread(void *args)
{
    while(1)
    {
    gdk_threads_enter();
    gtk_entry_set_text(entry2,"random stuff");
    gdk_threads_leave();

    }
}
```

Comment: `gdk_threads_enter` and related functions are deprecated since version 3.6. You should consider switching to propagation of work to the main thread through idle callbacks. For details see [documentation on this](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk3-Threads.description).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this could be an issue (don't know GTK) but maybe there is a race condition if the thread acquires the lock before the gtk_main has started.

Then you could try:

```
gdk_threads_enter();

//Multithreaded functions
g_thread_create(argument_thread, (gpointer)label7, FALSE, &error );

gtk_main();
gdk_threads_leave();
```

Moreover you should temporize your loop:

```
void *argument_thread(void *args)
{
    while(1)
    {
        gdk_threads_enter();
        gtk_entry_set_text(entry2,"random stuff");
        gdk_threads_leave();

        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

Certainly more responsive.

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved the problem using g_timeout e gthread:http://www.freemedialab.org/wiki/doku.php?id=programmazione:gtk:gtk_e_i_thread

Basically I use 3 functions, one that launches the thread, one that does the job without manipulating widgets (thread) and a third type that serves as a timeout timer checking every n seconds certain values ​​written by the thread and updates the ' graphic interface.

Or you can use "g_idle_add" : http://www.freemedialab.org/wiki/doku.php?id=programmazione:gtk:gtk_e_i_thread#versione_con_g_idle_add

gdk_threads_enter() and gdk_threads_leave() are deprecated from 3.6 version of Gtk.

Comment: Speaking of Gtkmm in C++ ( but this is just a wrapper so these functions also exist in c or any other gtk i just dont know their exact name) GLib offers a "Dispatcher" object, which you can connect a function to and then use it inside a thread that is not the GTK thread, and call the connected function which will then be executed in the GTK thread context, so you can use the GUI functions there. I think this is a very handsome method, especially since you are not required to have a timer running in the background.